Unable to upgrade a version of an already created managed package
While creating first version of a managed package, I had some components in it like lwc, triggers, custom objects etc but when I tried to add some more components in the managed package,a newer version is created, but it shows the error the package can't be upgraded, Try deleting the older versions first. However, basically it is imposibble in salesforce to uninstall a version. I also tried for unlisting it, but nothing worked. Can you suggest the ways for it

Can you provide the original error messages, instead of rephrasing them? That makes it easier to understand the actual problems you may have encountered.

Are you sure you created a Managed Released package and not a Managed Beta package.  If you created a Beta package and installed it in an org, you will not be able to upgrade it.  You must delete it from the org where it is installed and then install the new version.
Beta packages have their uses as you can modify for debugging but the main benefit I see is simply to not burn a number.  If you are simply hacking around with experiments to get some experience, you may want to build managed released packages so you can keep upgrading.  A lot depends on complexity of setup after install.  If it takes an hour of configuration after install to configure, beta packages can be a pain as every time you upgrade, you have to delete first which means going through the configuration again.

Cannot upgrade beta package
You cannot upgrade a beta package, because developers can make incompatible changes to a package that has been released as a beta. To install a newer version of the package, you must first uninstall the existing version.

Did you determine that you indeed built a beta package?

yes,, and your reply helped
